# generalized eigenvector to solve system of ODE (matrix exponential)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a 4x4 matrix, A, with initial value problem

**x'**=A**x**, **x**(0) = ξ<sub>0</sub>

where ξ<sub>0</sub> ∈ R<sup>4</sup> is a vector such that (A − 3I)<sup>3</sup>
ξ<sub>0</sub> = 0

but ξ<sub>1</sub> = (A − 3I)ξ<sub>0</sub> $\neq$ 0 and ξ2 = (A − 3I)<sup>2</sup>ξ<sub>0</sub> $\neq$ 0.

Make the change of variable **x** = e<sup>3t</sup>**y**, and derive an equation **y'**= B**y** (find B).

Then solve the initial value problem **y'**=B**y**, **y**(0) = ξ<sub>0</sub> representing **y** in terms of ξ<sub>0</sub>, ξ<sub>1</sub>, and ξ<sub>2</sub>. [Suggestion: use the matrix exponential.]

I have no idea how to get started but I found the following that looks relevant in my notes:

Let λ be an eigenvalue of A. Some vector η= 0 is a generalized eigenvector corresponding to λ if (A−λI)<sup>m</sup>η= 0 for some integer m≥1.  The smallest m for which this holds (so that(A−λI)<sup>m-1</sup>η $\neq$ 0 but (A−λI)<sup>m</sup>η = 0) is called the rank of η.

Any guidance and links to similar problems where I could understand the approach to solving this question would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions instead of specialized Unicode characters. That’ll likely be less work for you, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$\mathbf x = e^{3t} \mathbf y, \tag 1$

whence

$\mathbf x' = 3e^{3t} \mathbf y + e^{3t}\mathbf y'; \tag 2$

we combine (2) with

$\mathbf x' = A\mathbf x, \tag 3$

and obtain

$3e^{3t} \mathbf y + e^{3t}\mathbf y' = A\mathbf x; \tag 4$

*via* (1),

$3e^{3t} \mathbf y + e^{3t}\mathbf y' = A e^{3t} \mathbf y = e^{3t} A\mathbf y; \tag 5$

thus,

$3 \mathbf y+ \mathbf y' = A\mathbf y, \tag 6$

or

$\mathbf y' = A\mathbf y - 3\mathbf y = A\mathbf y - 3 I \mathbf y = (A - 3I)\mathbf y; \tag 7$

set

$B = A - 3I; \tag 8$

then

$\mathbf y' = B\mathbf y; \tag 9$

the solution to this equation with

$\mathbf y(0) = \xi_0 \tag{10}$

is

$\mathbf y(t) = e^{Bt} \xi_0 = e^{(A - 3I)t}\xi_0; \tag{11}$

we use the given $(A - 3I)^i\xi_0$, $1 \le i \le 3$, to compute $e^{(A - 3I)t}\xi_0$:

$\mathbf y(t) = \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{(A - 3I)^j t^j}{j!} \xi_0$
$= \xi_0 + t (A - 3I) \xi_0 + \dfrac{1}{2} t^2 (A - 3I)^2 \xi,  \tag{12}$

where the higher-order terms vanish since

$(A - 3I)^3 \xi_0 = 0 \tag{13}$

implies

$(A - 3I)^j \xi_0 = (A - 3I)^{j - 3} (A - 3I)^3 \xi_0 = 0, \; \forall j \ge 3; \tag{14}$

thus in the light of

$(A - 3I)^j \xi_0 = \xi_j, \; j = 1, 2, \tag{15}$

(12) becomes

$\mathbf y(t) = \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{(A - 3I)^j t^j}{j!} \xi_0 = \xi_0 + t \xi_1 + \dfrac{1}{2} t^2 \xi_2, \tag{16}$

the sought-for solution.